# Struggling to understand Python Output (Unicode, UTF-8, different Python Versions)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

#### Environment setup

I'm using iTerm2 with default encoding UTF-8.

#### 1/ Confusion

Starting Python2.7 Interpreter, I don't understand why we see two different outputs for seemingly the same functionality:

```py
>>> print('你好') 
你好

### vs

>>> '你好'
'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'
```

I thought simply hitting enter implicitly invokes the `print()` function - why do we observe different output? What are the intermediate steps that I'm missing here?

#### 2/ Confusion

On another note, the same code produces different output in different python version:

Python2.7

```py
>>> print('\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd')
你好
```

Python3

```py
>>> print('\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd')
ä½ å¥½
```

Can someone explain why this is the case? I would guess Python2.7 forwards the binaries to stdout as-is which may be the UTF-8 equivalent of 你好. What does Python3 do differently here then?

I think there's some interplay between terminal output, shell environment and encoding of string sin different python versions that I don't quite understand. I understand UTF-8, Unicode, ASCII, but can't connect the pieces together.

Thanks!

Comment: To the first question (or first example code block), its the difference between calling `print(str(var))` vs `print(repr(var))`, they aren't exactly the same, but sometimes they output the same thing. Print calls `str`, where as just putting it in the REPL calls `repr`

Comment: To answer the second question, scroll down to [Python 2 vs Python 3 String Handling](https://timothybramlett.com/Strings_Bytes_and_Unicode_in_Python_2_and_3.html)

Comment: Not sure if this is for education purpose (which is cool) or something else, but if you are developing new code, don't use Python2.7 as it is [no longer supported](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/). Stick with Python3. I say that just because I see you are a JavaScipt programmer and may not know this tidbit of information.

Comment: thanks for the comments, seems like they give me a very good direction. I'll try to compile a comprehensive answer based on those. this is only for educational purposes:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `print` outputs the `str()` representation of an object.  Without `print` in the interactive interpreter, the `repr()` representation of an object is output.  For strings the `repr()` is a debug output with escape codes for non-printable, non-ASCII characters; whereas the `str()` output is "pretty".

   Classes can specify their `repr()` and `str()` format.  Example:

   ```
   >>> class Test:
   ...   def __repr__(self):
   ...     return 'repr_of_Test'
   ...   def __str__(self):
   ...     return 'str_of_Test'
   ...
   >>> t = Test()
   >>> t
   repr_of_Test
   >>> print(t)
   str_of_Test
   ```
2. Python 2.7 `str` type is actually equivalent to the Python 3 `bytes` type.  Bytes are directly written to the terminal and interpreted in the terminals default encoding.  Note that the bytes in your string were UTF-8 because your source file was written in or your terminal was using UTF-8.  On a Windows console that supports Chinese you would get bytes encoded in the active code page:

   ```
   C:\>chcp 936
   Active code page: 936

   C:\>py -2
   Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:22:17) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> '你好'
   '\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'
   ```

   Python 3 `str` type is Unicode strings, which are then encoded in the default terminal encoding when output (caveat, later versions of Python 3 on Windows will use the Windows Unicode APIs to write to the Windows `cmd.exe` terminal directly, and not use the default encoding).

   So your Python 2.7 `print` sends UTF-8-encoded bytes directly to the terminal where they were interpreted as UTF-8, while your Python 3 example interprets each escape code as a Unicode codepoint.  for example `'\xe4'` is actually Unicode U+00E4 `ä` (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS) which is exactly what was printed.  Print the Unicode codepoints for your Chinese and it will work correctly.

   ```
   >>> print('\u4f60\u597d')
   你好
   ```

   Compared to Python 2, this is much more consistent than byte strings that depend on the user’s code page to work correctly.